# Laravel 6 ORM Time-out

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I loop the data, it will show **504 Gateway Time-out**.

> Timesheets table : 15,000 records
>
> Employees Table: 400 records
>
> Manpower Table: 100, 000 records.

If I get 3 tables in SQL just take 0.1ms. Any other solution for my case? Thanks All.

```php
$timesheets = Timesheets::where('type', 'Overtime')->get();

foreach ($timesheets as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($employeesUuid = Employees::where('employees_number', $value->employees_id)->first()->employees_uuid)) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($value->start_dt)->format('Y-m-d');

        $manpower = Manpower::with('pwra.purchaseOrder')
            ->where('employees_uuid', $employeesUuid)
            ->whereDate('register_date', $date)
            ->first();
        // What I want
        if (!empty($manpower)) {
            $timesheets[$key]->po_number = $manpower->pwra->purchaseOrder->first()->po_number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy god man, your problem clearly is that PHP cannot handle 115,400 models in the default time, I would say even in 5 minutes... it is a lot of models for 1 request to handle... you would even run out of memory... What are you trying to do with each `$manpower` as in this code you are only getting it and done ? Any work you are going to do, in the worst case, is over 100k models... that is an absolute **no-no**, you would have to dispatch a `job` with that model so it would do what you want with it... Explain more where are you using this, what do you want to do with that variable and extras.

Comment: I would assign one of the data to `$timesheets` collections from `$manpower` but I'm already adding the filter in $manpower which is `employees_uiud` and `register_date `. I added `what i want`

Answer (score 0):

First of all why don't you use relations `hasOneThrough` or `hasManyThrough` for `Timesheet` and `Manpower`. You can also have relation between `TimeSheet` and `Employee`.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

504 Gateway timeout error is not related to memory leak out. It is related to  server response which could be due to weak internet or any code issue.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504

Other than that, you can you lazy collections to save the memory, if you think memory is leaking out and breaking the system.

Comment: I cannot use the relation between `Timesheet` and  `Manpower`. it is because the they are not come from the same system, the id does not match with each others

Comment: @BryantTang What do you mean by not coming from the same system?

Comment: that's means the timesheets table comes from API which is another system.

Comment: @BryantTang Then you need to debug whether your API is working or not. You need to specify it in your question that you are fetching the data from API.

Comment: it works for the API, because I have been saved into my database. The `timesheets` table which is fetched the data from API.